# Sometimes commands do not terminate after upgrading to R 4.0 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, r, rstudio

I have upgraded R (from 3.6 to 4.0) and RStudio (from 1.1 to 1.2.5) a few days ago, and Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 yesterday.

Since then, R *sometimes* never terminates when executing certain commands: `ivreg` (from package `AER`), `summary` (of a logit regression) and `logitmfx` (from package `mfx`). Sometimes these commands run fine, but most of the time I have to kill the process (`killall rstudio`) because R won't terminate the execution, even when pressing the red Stop button in RStudio.

When I tried `example('AER')`, it worked fine. Then I re-installed the package `AER`. It threw 10 warnings of type `In readLines(file, skipNul = TRUE) :  cannot open compressed file '/usr/lib/R/site-library/[package]/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'` where `[package]` is `abind`, `colorspace`, `dichromat`... (but not `AER`).

Since then `example('AER')` throws a warning: `no help found for ‘AER’`.

I've removed and reinstalled R 4.0: it didn't help. Besides, the `apt purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*` threw a warning: `dpkg: warning: while removing r-base-core, directory '/usr/lib/R/site-library' not empty so not removed`. Also, there was a bunch of `Package [package] is not installed, so not removed`, including for `[package]` equal to `r-cran-abind` and the other listed above (this `purge` also returned a bunch of `Note, selecting [package] for glob 'r-cran-*'`).

I haven't tried using R without RStudio. I was probably working on RStudio during the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. Also, I can't recall if this issue started after I upgraded R and RStudio (which would be my best guess) or after I upgraded Ubuntu (a day or two later).

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided via `r-sig-debian` [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2020-May/003177.html) by Dirk Eddelbuettel and Sébastien Villemot.

I don't know if this is necessary, but I first did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

and select `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3` (instead of `pthread`).

Then (this worked):

```
sudo apt install  libopenblas-openmp-dev
sudo apt remove libopenblas-pthread-dev libopenblas0-pthread
```